# Strange icons artefact on app launcher

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, launcher

I have QMobile Noir LT250 running Android KitKat. As you can see on the image, two applications have strange icons. I have uninstalled one app and reinstalled it again, but it didn't solve it.

I have one option that I can perform a factory reset to solve it, but I don't want to do it.

Any suggestions?

[image: two apps with strange icons]

<sub>Click to enlarge screenshot</sub>

Comment: just try to clear cache.

Comment: You mean clear cache by antivirus?i have performed that many times.

Comment: no. by using recovery options

Comment: What kind of recovery?Explain little bit.

Comment: Which phone you're using?

Comment: Q mobile LT 250(android kit kat).

Comment: N.B : Back up before any operations . http://nmafzal.com/2013/07/18/how-to-factory-reset-your-android-q-mobile-if-touch-screen-is-broken-or-not-working/  You not requested to remove SIM and and SD card. Power off and power on by pressing Volume up + Power button. it will power on in recovery mode,   Inside this you can see a menu option called "wipe cache partition". Select it.

Comment: I have tried but it does not work,i think my phone has not this option(power off,again power on+volume up button).Unfortunately one more app added with same issue when i power on again.Now total three apps have strange artefact.Now ?

Comment: Try this : uninstall app, the goto internal storage(where app installed, commonly on internal SD). You can find a folder named `apps` ( path : /internal storage/apps ), which contains several app icon png files, try to delete it and reinstall app. OR  just try to install any other launcher application..

Comment: I have searched,i found a folder named as app but it did not contain .png files it contained .apk files.But finally peoblem has fixed by installing launcher(lollipop). Thanks Rahul.But there should be a way to fix this in previous launcher.I don't know how this problem occured.

Comment: Go to Settings -> Apps -> All apps -> that launcher app -> Force stop -> Clear data. Now switch to that launcher app and see if the app drawer still contains those icons.

Comment: It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have just installed Marshmallow launcher to get rid of that artefact. On the new launcher, the interface was new, no artefact. However, the artefact was still there on the stock launcher. Whenever I go to that launcher, that artefact was there.

Then after a few days, I just unintentionally go to stock launcher, then you know what, there was no artefact, the problem was solved!

Recently I have just found a way to get to the recovery option in my mobile. If I will ever face that artefact problem, then I will try to clean cache to see it solves or not as some of you said me to do this. Thanks guys!